# Expat health insurance for a diabetic

Tags: health-insurance, thailand

A few months ago I started looking at getting a new health insurance policy. My employer provides me with an inadequate one, and with retirement a mere 20 years away I thought perhaps it would be a good idea to get one now rather than be denied when I need it the most.

While visiting family in Europe, this search got a whole lot more complicated. I went to the hospital for something unrelated and was told (not officially diagnosed) that I have type 2 diabetes. As I am not a resident, I no longer have access to universal healthcare there.

I'm a long-time expat. I currently live in Thailand, but as I expect to move around I am decidedly looking for a policy that provides coverage globally (although no need for the USA as I do not plan to retire there).

I have been contacting insurance companies and so far the response has been as expected: pre-existing conditions are not covered. Some do and some don't cover potential future complications. It's difficult to judge how honest those statements of coverage are; these are insurance companies after all.

I'm hoping there are some diabetics out there that have gone through this before, and can provide me with recommendations. Are there companies I don't know that do provide coverage? What experience do diabetics have dealing with expat insurance companies? Should I just accept this is going to be a budget item for me going forward?

This situation is quite worrying to me. I appreciate this is quite a broad question, but I would very much appreciate your comments.

Comment: The best option would be to get an insurance coverage from a company local to where you actually live, and even better is to be covered by the universal coverage there (i.e.: be a legal permanent/long term resident).

Comment: @littleadv Thank you for sharing your thoughts. Getting a local insurance would not cover me moving to different countries, which is in the cards for me. In addition, local insurance companies here do not cover pre-existing conditions either. Not mandated by law, so why would they? I am a legal long-term resident, but sadly there is no universal coverage.

Comment: when you move countries - figure out the insurance for the new country. In the meantime - it would help if you say what is the country you're *currently* in.

Comment: @littleadv Thailand. It says so in the question.